# Microsoft Access Duplicate Output Destination workaround

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a column containing 123 unique Raw Material Names and another column called OutgoingRawMaterial, the idea being that we can look at the table and see that 270 units of Ingredient A left the company etc.

I wanted to create an update query which would update the related OutgoingRawMaterial with the figure from the query 'qrySumManufacturingRawMaterials' which contains the figures I want. The Update Query works fine for individual records, as below:

```
Field: OutgoingRawMaterial
Table: tblRawMaterialsManufactured
Update to: [tblSumManufacturingRawMaterials Query].[Expr1]
Criteria: [RawMaterial] Like "Raw Material 1*"
```

The problem is that I want to do the same for all 123 records and don't know how to do this, short of creating 123 queries and running them all from a macro or VBA. I was also going to create a single query with all 123 Raw Materials, using a different 'LIKE' to isolate them, but get the "Duplicate Output Destination 'tblRawMaterialsManufactured.OutgoingRawMaterial'" I can confirm that I only have one column named 'OutgoingRawMaterial'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

The answer below is how you would normally solve this. The way you're trying to do it by having 2 columns with a bunch of records and a 3rd column with the sum is actually considered a [bad design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) because your third column is not related to the first 2 columns. You'll have tell me more to understand how that third column will work - does it contain 123 sum (aggregate) values while the first 2 columns contains say hundreds of individual values?

---

The easiest approach would be to delete everything and recreate the table. For example, let's say that 'qrySumManufacturingRawMaterials'  outputs something like this:

Raw1 | 1

Raw2 | 2

...

And OutgoingRawMaterial has the same format then you can just do a [INSERT INTO SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp):

```
DELETE FROM OutgoingRawMaterial; 
INSERT INTO OutgoingRawMaterial SELECT 'qrySumManufacturingRawMaterials'
```

There are many variations on this - for example if the query outputs different column names you can change the query to INSERT INTO OutgoingRawMaterial (Col1, Col2, ...) so if you need more help please update the question.

Comment: Hi Charlie,Thanks so much for this.

It looks like this would work and you're also correct in that the original design left me over a barrel so I think I will delete and normalise the tables.

The 'INSERT INTO SELECT' is done in SQL, is it, or can this also be done in VBA?

Comment: VBA cannot interact with Access except through SQL so yes it's a SQL statement that's executed by VBA using an Access driver. Think of it as VBA printing a document. VBA knows nothing about printers but it can tell a printer driver that it wants to print.

Comment: @Juddles - Any update on this? Was the problem solved?

Comment: Hi Charlie, Yes, I resolved it by redesigning the database and getting a commitment from my bosses not to add in anything else to the scope...which they did anyway ha ha!

Comment: Your solution was the right way to go though, it was just that so much was tacked on that it became more efficient just to redo massive parts of the architecture